# Выборка данных из бд MS SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. Есть проект winforms. Использую Entity.
Есть 2 класса:

```
class Systems
    {
        public int SystemsId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }

class Users
    {
        public int UsersId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }

        public int SystemsId { get; set; }
        public virtual Systems System { get; set; }
    }
```

На форме вот так вот подтягиваются данные:

```
Context db;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            db = new Context();
            db.System.Load();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = db.System.Local.ToBindingList();

        }
```

Но почему то когда я в отладке заглядываю в дата соурс, там у каждой системы коллекция Users равна null. Почему так происходит? ведь по внешнему ключу данные должны подтягиваться. Вот скрины моих данных.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, может я делаю что то не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все дело в lazy load(ленивой загрузке) у Entity. Суть в том, что он подтягивает данные, только тогда, когда необходимо. Ты локально загрузил таблицу System, но Users ты не загрузил, соответственно не на что ссылаться.

```
        db = new Context();
        db.System.Load();
        db.Users.Load();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = db.System.Local.ToBindingList();
```

P.S. лучше не загружай локально данные, а сразу пиши db.System.ToBindingList(). Entity умный, и подгрузит сам все необходимые данные.

Comment: Немножко не понял, что значит не загружать локально а сразу писать `db.System.Local.ToBindingList()` ? Не могли бы привести пример?

Comment: dataGridView1.DataSource = db.System.ToBindingList();